# Make the left and right margins the same width

Tags: html, css

What is the way to make the left (large) margin as small as right?
I know about CSS resets, but still cannot figure out the actual working way.

```
<body>
<div id="quote">Foo</div>
<p>Foo</p>
</body> 

<style>
body { padding-left: 10%; background-color: rgb(255,205,205); }
#quote { margin-left: -10%; padding-left: 10%; background-color: rgb(205,255,205); }

/* I can use `calc` as a value, but I understand that it is not 
   the clever way */
/* #quote { margin-left: calc(-10% - 16px); } */

</style>
```

The problem:

[image]

The behaviour I would like to implement:

[image]

Comment: Why is calc() not clever?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all remove default margin and padding which browser taking.

like:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then,

Change css like following. There is not need of negative margin.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 205, 205);
    padding: 0 1%;
}

#quote {
    background-color: rgb(205, 255, 205);
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkwh5r6r/)**

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to reset **all** element's margin/padding like that, at least not without fully explaining the effect it will have.

Comment: @LGSon It will remove all default margin/padding. So, we can give margin/padding as expected and got expected result. Just try to remove `* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}` from Fiddle. It will take extra margin which is not given

Comment: I know what it does, but this will reset not only, in this case the p and body, also all other elements like ul, li, h1-6, etc., and that might not be wanted.

Comment: @LGSon It will useful in future when they add any other elements. I don't think only this much element they use.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
body { background-color: rgb(255,205,205); }
p { padding-left: 10%; }
#quote { background-color: rgb(205,255,205); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a `width` to your div and set `margin` to auto

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa9q2uv0/1/)

```css
body {  margin 0;background-color: rgb(255,205,205);}
#quote {  margin:auto; width:95%; background-color: rgb(205,255,205); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style:

```css
p {margin-left:16px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you want ?

```css
body {background-color: rgb(255,205,205); }
#quote {margin: 0 1%; padding: 0 10%; background-color: rgb(205,255,205); }
p {margin: 0 1%; padding: 0 13%;}
```

```html
<div id="quote">Foo</div>
<p>Foo</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
background-color: rgb(255,205,205);
}
#quote {
margin: 0 auto;
width:90%
background-color: rgb(205,255,205);
padding-left:10%;
}
p{
margin-left:14%;
}
```

[For Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bejynqon/)