# Make the margins the same

Tags: html, css

I [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522178/make-the-the-left-and-right-margins-the-same-width) the question about this **kind** of problem, but I was quite unclear in the task, so the all answers (there were **a lot** of answers) were about **another** problem.

**Due to a large amount of answers, I decided to ask another question, instead of editing the previous. Because the previus question will be also useful for someone**.

Here is the image:

[image]

Here is the code. May be someone can help me?

```
<h1>OK</h1>
<div style="background: rgb(255,205,205); padding-left: 10%;">Padding 10%</div>
<div style="background: rgb(205,255,205); margin-left: 10%;">Margin 10%</div>

<h1>OK</h1>
<div class="class-wrapper">
<div style="background: rgb(255,205,205); padding-left: 10%;">Padding 10%</div>
<div style="background: rgb(205,255,205); margin-left: 10%;">Margin 10%</div>
</div>

<h1>Why?? And how to avoid?</h1>
<p>For some reason I need to use the both wrappers.
What is the way to fix the left alignment?</p>

<div class="class-wrapper1">
<div class="class-wrapper2">
<div style="background: rgb(255,205,205); padding-left: 10%;">Padding 10%</div>
<div style="background: rgb(205,255,205); margin-left: 10%;">Margin 10%</div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
.class-wrapper  {padding-left: 10%; margin-left: -10%; margin-top: 1em; }
.class-wrapper1 {padding-left: 10%; margin-top: 1em; }
.class-wrapper2 {margin-left: -10%; margin-top: 1em; }
</style>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I decided that it is more convenient just to write a simple HTML page (the code in my post), rather than write it as additional text.

Comment: I don't see the unequal, bad margins. What do I miss?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I tried to make the 3rd version looks like the previos two.

Comment: Are you wondering why the vertical size of the white part is different?

Comment: looks fine to me [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jg2sf9my/)

Comment: Oh, I see now. You have a shift in the pink and green bar to the right! Is that the problem?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, yes you are right. This is not distinctly visible in a small monitors, that is why I posted a wide screenshot. // And also please see the comment to silviagreen's answer. I should use both wrappers - one with padding and another with negative margin. This is the rules of the game.

Comment: I see... My guess is that there's some confusion between what we **think** is set in the styles and what's **actually** set. I see that you've got margins/paddings set both by style in the tags and the classes. It's great for laboration on how it works (kudo that!) but you might be better off if you start creating jsFiddles and setting the examples there. It's going to be much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @dippas, please see my previous comment to Konrad. In JSFiddle this looks fine because the screen is not wide enought. Try to expand the JSFiddle output area, for example, and you can see a little dis-alignment.

Comment: *I should use both wrappers - one with padding and another with negative margin. This is the rules of the game* what rules??  why can't you just use one wrapper?

Comment: I think no. Because it just simplified example, to make it easier to read and answer (and downvoted 3 times... well, ok). I know about [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @dippas I think the OP wants to understand **why** it happens, rather than just make it go away. You have to applaud the curiosity - it's purely academic want-to-know and not engineerous what-to-resolve. I like that. ANd also, he made the picture. That takes time so we have a proof of effort, showing he's invested into learning.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using percentages for your margins and padding. The margins/padding of `class-wrapper2` is based on the smaller size of the box `class-wrapper1` that it is contained in.

Because of that you need to set a larger negative margin on it (11.1%)

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10.5%; outline: 1px solid red; height: 100%;width: 100%"> </div>
    <h1>OK</h1>
    <div style="background: rgb(255,205,205); padding-left: 10%;">Padding 10%</div>
    <div style="background: rgb(205,255,205); margin-left: 10%;">Margin 10%</div>

    <h1>OK</h1>
    <div class="class-wrapper">
    <div style="background: rgb(255,205,205); padding-left: 10%;">Padding 10%</div>
    <div style="background: rgb(205,255,205); margin-left: 10%;">Margin 10%</div>
    </div>

    <h1>Why?? And how to avoid?</h1>
    <p>For some reason I need to use the both wrappers.
    What is the way to fix the left alignment?</p>

    <div class="class-wrapper1">
    <div class="class-wrapper2">
    <div style="background: rgb(255,205,205); padding-left: 10%;">Padding 10%</div>
    <div style="background: rgb(205,255,205); margin-left: 10%;">Margin 10%</div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <style>
    div {box-sizing: border-box;}
    .class-wrapper  {padding-left: 10%; margin-left: -10%; margin-top: 1em; }
    .class-wrapper1 {padding-left: 10%; margin-top: 1em; }
    .class-wrapper2 {margin-left: -11.1%; margin-top: 1em; }
    </style>
```

Comment: Thank you, that bring the light to the problem (Dippas also mentioned that, but your answer was the first). But may be there is some way to avoid `11.1`? A more universal way? Or not?

Comment: This problem (and the problem of not being able to know how tall an element is) are the reason there are so many CSS grid systems. You could pick one of them. [Comparison Grid of Grid Systems](http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html)

Answer (score 1):

This code will solve the problem

```
.class-wrapper1{

}

.class-wrapper2 {
 margin-left: -10%;
 margin-top: 1em;
 padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/558w5vv5/1/)

Comment: Thank you, but I should to use the both wrappers - one with padding, and one with negative margin. This is "the rules of the game".

Answer (score 0):

These rulesets always worked well for me, they set all lengths (i.e. margins, padding, border, etc.) to 0 and defines how every element is measured by the same standard (**[`box-sizing: border-box`](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)**). There are some other properties from [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) as well, minor but nice to have if the need arrises.

Put these rules at the top of your CSS. As it is a reset, you'll probably have to redo your layout a little, but now you'll adjust to get a margin of 10px as you expect instead of 18px and you'll get the same results with a different element as well. The reason why you weren't before is because every browser has different defaults so bringing everything down to 0 probably will help unless you're running your site on a cookie cutter host like Word-Press.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 500 16px/1.428 'Arial';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```